# How to get the starting point of a seeking event in HTML5 Video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I find that in HTML5 video when users perform a seek action by clicking the controls, there is no way to get the time before seeking.

What I want to do is whenever users seek video to a certain point, system will know exactly at what point before users seek. For example, if a user is watching video untill 2:00 and then click the control at 4:00, we need to keep track of the time 2:00. I have tried seeking and seeked event but can't get the time 2:00. It always return me the time 4:00. Is there any solution?

Comment: MDN defines `seeking` event as “sent when a seek operation begins.” If that doesn’t give access to the current position _before_ seeking starts though, then maybe you could monitor the `currentTime` property in an interval, and see when it changes by a delta that is “higher” then what would to be expected during normal continuous playback …

Comment: @laser_wizard I use google chrome and firefox to test and find that if users seek when the video is paused then seeking and seeked event will be fired. If users seek when the video is playing, events will be fired in the order of paused,seeking,play,seeked. I could not get the exactly time before seeking no matter what kind of event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to track this thanks to `timeupdate` event, with a short delay :

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');
video.BP = 0;

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e){
var that = this;
(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
   that.BP=that.currentTime;
   }, 500);
  }).call(that);}
  );

video.addEventListener('seeking', function(e){
  log('boringPart = '+this.BP+
        " gone to "+this.currentTime)
  })
function log(txt){document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = txt;}
```

```html
<video controls="true" autoplay="true" height="200" width="600"><source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"><source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"></video>
<p style="position:absolute; top: 0.5em;left: 3em; color: #FFF;background:#000"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

use a click event to track the click that leads to the seeking event.
Example using video.js

```
var clickTime = 0;
this.controlBar.on('click', function(){
    clickTime = player.currentTime();
});

this.on('seeking', function(){
    seekTime = clickTime;
    //do stuff
});
```